# Low Search Shortcuts 404 not found

Tags: low-search

Low Search Shortcuts look really neat, and I want one for Christmas, trouble is it keeps throwing 404s at me. I tried it on a couple of EE builds with no luck, so I can eliminate version compatibilities.

Looking out there I found some mention of mod_security, I've only ever had this on new server setups, and not on MAMP PRO, plus when I deployed to the staging server I still get the problem.

I've run out of steam on this and I can easily use http://domain.com/home/search?keywords=hello as an alternative, but would be nice to know what's going on, so any tips on using Shortcuts will be most welcomed.

Comment: Where are you getting the 404s? In the CP or the front-end? Are you using Structure or any other add-ons I should know of? What does the URI look like when getting the 404?

Comment: Frontend. No add-ons, working on a clean install. URL is same on return http://basic:8888/search/tested as a 404 with no debugger.

Comment: And I take it `search` is a template group and `tested` is a shortcut name? Can you share the code in the `search/index` template?

Comment: Search is not a group, tested is a shortcut. Direct link to template is http://basic:8888/home/search/tested - not 404, but shows ALL the entries instead.

Answer (score 1):

In [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search), [Shortcuts](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/shortcuts) are saved searches (or a set of parameters) that you can give a name. The search results are then triggered by using that name.

**Note: the shortcut is triggered by its name, not by a full URL** (like how the Pages module works).

Consider this simple example in the template `search/shortcuts`:

```
{exp:low_search:shortcuts group_id="1"}
  <a href="{path="search/shortcuts/{shortcut_name}"}">{shortcut_label}</a><br>
{/exp:low_search:shortcuts}

{if segment_3}
  {exp:low_search:results shortcut="{segment_3}"}
    <p>{entry_id}: {title}</p>
  {/exp:low_search:results}
{/if}
```

It loops through the shortcuts in group 1 and generates links to `search/shortcuts/SHORTCUT-NAME`. The Results tag then takes that shortcut name, applies the parameters to itself, thus generating the filtered search results.

**Regular EE routing rules still apply**, so if `search` isn't a valid template group and you have [Strict URLs enabled](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#strict-urls), a 404 will be generated.

You say you have no `search` template group, so I'm guessing that's the case here. If you create a `search` template group, and add the Results tag to its `index` template, the 404s should go away.

Comment: I've already tried using a 'search' group with the results tag in the index page, changing query param to segment_2 + segment_3. So if we forget about 404, why do you think the shortcut does not filter out the keyword and shows all entries?

Comment: Are you using `query="SHORTCUT-NAME"`? Because you should be using `shortcut="SHORTCUT-NAME"`. If you add the Results tag code to your original question, that will help me understand what you're doing, too.

Comment: So... by adding shortcut="{segment_2}" in the results tag it works - yes it does! - sorry if I missed this in your docs, it does say it's a supported parameter, but I didn't pick up on that it had to be a required param. thanks!